# JPA : illegal attempt to dereference collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable 
{
    private List<Request> sentRequest;
    private List<Request> receivedRequest;
    private Profile profile;
}

public  List<Object> getUserProfiles(Integer userid) 
{
    query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT p from Profile p1,Profile p2 WHERE " + 
            "p1.user.sentRequest.sender.id (:id) NOT IN " + 
            " p2.user.receivedRequest.receiver.id and " + 
            "p1.user.id NOT IN (:id)"
        ).setParameter("id",userid);
```

I tried above query it's throwing  illegal attempt to dereference collection.
The relationship are
User - Profile OneToOne and User - Request OneToMany

I want to select all user Profiles those have not sent request and except own profile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part of code `p1.user.sentRequest.sender.id (:id) NOT IN` the parameter must be after the `NOT IN` like this `p1.user.sentRequest.sender.id NOT IN (:id)`